# regular expression in python - can't find a specific string

Tags: python, regex

I started to learn regex in python and I've got the following task:

I need to write a script taking those 2 strings:

```
string_1 = 'merchant ID 1234, device ID 45678, serial# 123456789'

string_2 = 'merchant ID 8765, user ID 531476, serial# 87654321'
```

and displaying only the strings which has `merchant ID ####` and `device ID ####` in them.

To check for the first condition I wrote the following line:

```
ex_1 = re.findall(r'\merchant\b\s\ID\b\s\d+', string_1)
print (ex_1)

output: ['merchant ID 1234'] - works fine!
```

Problem is I can't get the other condition for some reason:

```
ex_2 = re.findall(r'\device\b\s\ID\b\s\d+', string_1)

output: [] - empty list.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use a web tool like https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because:

```
ex_2 = re.findall(r'\device\b\s\ID\b\s\d+', string_1)
                    ^^
```

Which matches a number, but `\m` in `\merchant` is still `m`. However you should remove the `\` which before `\ID` and `\device` like:

```
>>> re.findall(r'device\b\sID\b\s\d+', string_1)
['device ID 45678']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your grouping is wrong. Use brackets for the grouping:

```
(merchant ID \d+|device ID \d+)
```

e.g.

```
>>>re.findall('(merchant ID \d+|device ID \d+)', string_1)
['merchant ID 1234', 'device ID 45678']
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the special character `'\'`. `'\device\'` matches with `[0-9] + 'evice'`. 
With [Pythex](http://pythex.org/) you can test your regex, and consult a great cheatsheet.